# How to Edit Windows Application GUI using resource file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a beginner in Microsoft Visual Studio , so this might be a bad question, but basically I can access a GUI for an application using Microsoft Visual Studio Resource file, and I just want to add a few gases to the GUI and have Visual Studio automatically update everything so that the new file has the new gases generated.

[image: Resource File Visual Studio]

Comment: The project would need to be re-compiled. You would probably have to also add code to handle the new text boxes. But to add new text boxes, you can copy-and-paste the existing labels/text boxes (use the mouse to select multiple).

Comment: I am able to copy paste normally, but once I rebuild solution, the GUI just shows the Icons that were previously made, not any new ones. But if I change the location of the pre-existing icons, the rebuilt solution reflects those changes

Comment: Of course you'll have to arrange the new stuff after you paste it...My guess is the generic ones labeled "gas" are programmatically shown/hidden with the "Add Gas" button. So what you want to do will involve some programming.